# How to enable outgoing requests of outgoing HTTP Connection on Google Cloud App Engine by proxy for Puppeteer and Request(http modules)?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, proxy, puppeteer

I am working on a Scraping App that uses puppeteer and is hosted on Google Cloud App Engine. This app works well locally then when on google cloud, it fails I suspect it has to do with the proxy that I need to configure. I have been trying to search but nothing has worked yet. The site that I am scraping is [http://status.wsu.ac.za/status/statuscheck.php](http://%20http://status.wsu.ac.za/status/statuscheck.php).

Following is the code I am using to scrape:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--headless",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    ],
  });

  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://status.wsu.ac.za/status/statuscheck.php");
  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });

  let content = await page.content();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Can you expand about what do you mean by failing? Do you get any error that you can share with us? If so, please edit your question to better understand what the issue is.